# How to center a div and position another div to the right?

Tags: css, html

I am having an issue with positioning a `div` in the middle and floating another `div` to the right of it. The `div` contains a `select` element and keeps going onto a new line.

I have tried many things. I would like the divs to be side by side and not to collapse when the page is minimized.

I tried to float the `div` with the id `theme` right but it pushes it onto a new line.

```
#theme {
    float: right;
}
```

You can see my problem in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bitmap90/2WuZ6/3/)

The desired solution looks like this:

[image: Image of desired solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way , wrap both `select & nav` in a div of fixed width and give `theme class` a width . It will position the divs like the image

```
<div class="wrap">    
<!-- all html here -->    
</div>

.theme
{
    float: right;
    width:100px; //say 100
}

 .wrap{
     width:1100px;
     margin:0 auto
   }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/IYifEN/1